# Bower mirror repository

Tags: javascript, dependencies, repository, nexus, bower

Using Maven, you get Maven repositories. Tools like Nexus ou Artifactory have the ability to mirror (or proxy) remote repositories and self-hosted ones to expose an aggregated view of all downloadable artifacts (or dependencies in the Bower jargon). You get the same mechanism for other dependency managers like Ivy oy Gradle (Maven, Ivy/Ant & Gradle are more than just dependency managers, but it's not the point here).

With Bower, you can set up remote registries from which dependencies will be downloaded. But a great thing in a corporate environment would be to have a self hosted repository working like those describe above.

I have search the Web but did not find any convincing solution. Did you know any of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I understand Bower uses npm and as such you can use [Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/npm/how-it-works/).

Support for npm repositories is also a requested feature for Nexus. If you are interested in that, vote on the [issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5852) and you might see it implemented in the not too distant future ;-)

In the meantime you can potentially use [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/)

Update 2015-03-13: NPM support has been available in Nexus OSS and Pro for a while now. Read more about setting it all up [in the documentation.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm.html) However to clarify the Bower repository format is different from the npm format. The Bower team is hoping to move everything to NPM and stop development and hosting, but that is an ongoing effort.

Update 2016-04-11: The new [release of Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.0](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/04/06/spring-into-the-future-nexus-repository-manager-3-0-release/) has full support for [npm](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/npm.html) and [bower](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bower.html).

Comment: Thanks. Asking myself how Nexus will accomodate polymorphic bower repository layout (not normalized as Maven 2 layout). Will get a look at your links.

Comment: Nexus is not tied to Maven and its repository format at all. It supports very different repos like NuGet, Yum, Maven, Deb and even plain site repo (which is a free form html hosting basically, mainly used for Maven generated sites).

Comment: Ok, good to now. I think this has been bring through Aether which supports polymorphic layouts?

Comment: No. It is just a the design of Nexus. Aether is the repo client library used in Maven and other tools.

Comment: An article on NPM blog that explains the pain to use NPM for client-side javascript, and the roadmap of NPM. As said above, we can hope Bower (and others) will use the NPM registries in future. http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging

Answer (score 1):

[private-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower) provide private bower registry hosting and public registry caching.

Answer (score 0):

[Artifactory Pro](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorypro_overview) can do this [now](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories). Although the reason I stumbled into this question on StackOverflow is that I'm trying to figure out how precisely to do it. I don't yet follow what if anything I'm supposed to do to support the Repository Layout.

Comment: As I read it, Artifactory Pro can do npm, but not yet bower. They do have an open jira for it, though: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6488

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype Nexus will have support for Bower in Nexus 3.  Once this is released, this will probably be the easiest solution, particularly for anyone doing Java development.   So make sure you check if this solution is available before just picking the "checked" solution.

Here's the ticket:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6884

Until that happens, go with private-bower:
https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower